# Invalid Resx file. Could not load type System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, properties

I have property on my usercontrol but when i add usercontrol to my foem and want to run, i got this error on visual studio 2010 but this error dosn't appear on VS 2008:
"Invalid Resx file. Could not load type System.Collections.Generic.List...."

```
[Serializable]
public class ActionPoint
{
public string CarInfo;
public string RightStationName;
public string RightStationInfo;
public string LeftStationName;
public string LeftStationInfo;

public ActionPoint()
{
}
}
public class Line : UserControl
{ 
   public List<ActionPoint> Stations
   {
   get { return Stations; }
   set { Stations = value; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does the form have an `ImageList`, and is the project targeting .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 8):

If you check in your resx-file, do you have a `data` section?

I have no idea what exactly happened but what worked for me was to remove the two data sections where the binary (serialized) data was stored:

```
  <data name="myListView1.DataSource" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
    <value>
        AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAJYBU2tvbGVwb3J0ZW5BZGRpbiwgVmVyc2lvbj0xLjAuMC4wLCBD
        dWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPW51bGxdXSwgbXNjb3JsaWIsIFZlcnNpb249NC4w
        LjAuMCwgQ3VsdHVyZT1uZXV0cmFsLCBQdWJsaWNLZXlUb2tlbj1iNzdhNWM1NjE5MzRlMDg5DAMAAABH
        U2tvbGVwb3J0ZW5BZGRpbiwgVmVyc2lvbj0xLjAuMC4wLCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tl
        eVRva2VuPW51bGwFAQAAAENTeXN0ZW0uQ29sbGVjdGlvbnMuR2VuZXJpYy5MaXN0YDFbW1Nrb2xlcG9y
        dGVuQWRkaW4uTW9kZWxzLkppcmFJdGVtAwAAAAZfaXRlbXMFX3NpemUIX3ZlcnNpb24EAAAiU2tvbGVw
        b3J0ZW5BZGRpbi5Nb2RlbHMuSmlyYUl0ZW1bXQMAAAAICAIAAAAJBAAAAAAAAAABAAAABwQAAAAAAQAA
        AAAAAAAEIFNrb2xlcG9ydGVuQWRkaW4uTW9kZWxzLkppcmFJdGVtAwAAAAs=
</value>
  </data>
  <data name="myListView2.DataSource" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
    <value>
        AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAJYBU2tvbGVwb3J0ZW5BZGRpbiwgVmVyc2lvbj0xLjAuMC4wLCBD
        dWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPW51bGxdXSwgbXNjb3JsaWIsIFZlcnNpb249NC4w
        LjAuMCwgQ3VsdHVyZT1uZXV0cmFsLCBQdWJsaWNLZXlUb2tlbj1iNzdhNWM1NjE5MzRlMDg5DAMAAABH
        U2tvbGVwb3J0ZW5BZGRpbiwgVmVyc2lvbj0xLjAuMC4wLCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tl
        eVRva2VuPW51bGwFAQAAAENTeXN0ZW0uQ29sbGVjdGlvbnMuR2VuZXJpYy5MaXN0YDFbW1Nrb2xlcG9y
        dGVuQWRkaW4uTW9kZWxzLkppcmFJdGVtAwAAAAZfaXRlbXMFX3NpemUIX3ZlcnNpb24EAAAiU2tvbGVw
        b3J0ZW5BZGRpbi5Nb2RlbHMuSmlyYUl0ZW1bXQMAAAAICAIAAAAJBAAAAAAAAAABAAAABwQAAAAAAQAA
        AAAAAAAEIFNrb2xlcG9ydGVuQWRkaW4uTW9kZWxzLkppcmFJdGVtAwAAAAs=
</value>
  </data>
```

Comment: This doesn't work; It's a temporary fix. next re-build, it's back!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create new UserControl and copy your code into its *.cs file? Maybe your resx file is damaged..

Update:

your question seems similar to [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/0b2230d5-1259-46b3-ba3d-df1b7fc1deeb/).